# Launching an Activity from intent only if application is not running

Tags: android, android-activity

My application has an Activity for logging in, `LoginActivity` and I have defined an intent filter for it so that if someone plugs in a USB device the LoginActivity is launched. This scenario works fine.

The code:

```
<activity
    android:name=".main.login.LoginActivity"
    ...
    >
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"/>
  </intent-filter>

  <meta-data
      android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
      android:resource="@xml/device_filter"
      />
</activity>
```

When the application is running, however, this happens:
I'm attaching the USB device and am "redirected" to the login screen (`LoginActivity`). In this scenario I don't want to launch a new activity.

What should I do to get the wanted behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your activity in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Answer (score -1):

you should put intent filter  like as below instead of your code .

```
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Using this code was like having no code at all (would not launch LoginActivity when app is not started)... Which is obvious of course since the action is incorrect. I'll try with the other action

Comment: Didn't work with:

       <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>